# Decoding JSON file in python with double quotes in value

Tags: python, json, decoding

I'm in need of a potential workaround of this problem.
I have a web service that extracts some data directly from database and saves it as a JSON file(as it turns out forcefully).

Normal and working slice of data is like this:

```
[
  {
    "number" : 1,
    "title" : "title 1",
    "description" : "description 1"
  },
  {
    "number" : 2,
    "title" : "title 2",
    "description" : "description 2"
  }
]
```

But sometimes description field in database may have copied e-mail from Outlook and then the JSON look like this:

```
[
  {
    "number" : 3,
    "title" : "title 3",
    "description" : "description by dawid.smith<"dawid@smith.com"> 1"
  },
  {
    "number" : 4,
    "title" : "title 4",
    "description" : "description 2"
  }
]
```

It's understandable to me that this:

```py
with open('json_test.json', 'r') as lista_json:
    jsony = json.load(lista_json)
```

won't work on JSON with double quotes around e-mail, because of:

```py
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 50 (char 98)
```

Given that the actual JSON may contain high number of entires I think it will be too much of an effort to regexping it seperetaly line by line if e-mail is found.

Is there any workaround that will somehow bypass the double quotes inside the value of key - 'description'?

Comment: Maybe this regex could help? `json_str = re.sub(r': \"(.*)\"$', lambda g: ': "' + g.group(1).replace('"', "'") + '"', broken_json_data, flags=re.M)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely but you still mean regexping the file before decoding it, right?

Comment: Yes. But it depends on your data, if it's feasible or not. But you can try...

Comment: well, it might be resource consuming with some of my json files that are quite large and big in size, but thanks anyway for some reply. Still, I'll look for decoding workaround.

Comment: Web service has bug - it should encode all chars properly. Isn't it easier to fix problem source ?

Comment: I was afraid that it might lead into this, but I think we will have to fix the web service. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse the input because it is not valid JSON. You'll have to fix it beforehand. Assuming the only bad cases you have are `<"` and `">`, you can do this with `sed` like so:

```sh
% sed -E 's/<"/\\"/g; s/">/\\">/g' input.txt | python -m json.tool     
[
    {
        "number": 3,
        "title": "title 3",
        "description": "description by dawid.smith\"dawid@smith.com\"> 1"
    },
    {
        "number": 4,
        "title": "title 4",
        "description": "description 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: yea, I think we will have to do it beforehand during web service work. thank you.